# Solving cyclotomic polynomials over finite fields

Tags: algorithms, modular-arithmetic, finite-fields

Suppose you are given two prime numbers, $p<q$ such that $p\mid\varphi(q)$.

My question can be stated in two equivalent manners:

1. Let $G$ be the group of units $\mathbb{Z}_q^\times. 
    $Is there an efficient algorithm that will enable me to find an element $g\in G$ (other than $1$) such that $g^p\equiv1$?
2. Is there an efficient algorithm that will let me solve the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_p(g)$ over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$?

Obviously, brute force can be used to find solutions, so my question is about an algorithm that can solve these questions in a manner that is significantly faster than brute force.

For $p=2$, the problem is easy, and the solution is that $g=q-1$.  The problem is more difficult for other values of $p$.

Let $H$ be the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_{q-1}$.  Finding an element $h_0\in H$ of order $p$ is trivial, as $h_0=\frac{q-1}{p}$ is a solution.  However, even though $G\cong H$, this doesn't help us unless we can also find an isomorphic mapping $\psi: H\rightarrow G$.  However, if we randomly guess possible values $g_0\in G$, we can stop as soon as we find an element of either order $p$ (giving us an immediate solution of $g=g_0$), or of order $q-1$ (giving us a mapping $\psi$, and a resulting solution $g=g_0^{h_0}$).  As there are $\varphi(p)$ elements in $G$ of order $p$ and $\varphi(q-1)$ elements of $G$ of order $q-1$, this guess and check algorithm, on average, will yield a solution in $\frac{\varphi(q)-2}{\varphi(p)+\varphi(q-1)}$ guesses (the $-2$ in the numerator comes from the fact that we don't need to bother checking the elements $1,q-1$, as we know their orders are 1 and 2, respectively). For any fixed value of $p$, this grows approximately linearly with $q$.

For $p=3$ or $p=5$, we can use the quadratic formula to solve for $\Phi_3$ or the quartic formula to solve for $\Phi_5$ respectively.  This gives us that for $p=3$, we have an example solution of $g=\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$  and for $p=5$, we have an example solution of $y=\sqrt{5}, g=\frac{y+1}{4}+\sqrt{\frac{5-y}{8}}$.  There are known algorithms for solving square roots in $\mathbb{F}_q$ that grow in runtime approximately linearly with the number digits of $q$, which makes them significantly faster for large $q$.

However, I can't find a way to extend this methodology to other values of $p$.  In order for the method to be applicable, we require that $\Phi_p$ have a known solution with radicals, and that every type of radical used in that explicit solution has an algorithm (more efficient than brute force) to solve over a finite field.  From a quick Google search, I failed to find any such algorithms for solving cube roots, and I also failed to find an explicit solution in radicals for $\Phi_7$ (although I did find articles stating that the Galois groups of the splitting fields of cyclotomic polynomials are all abelian, which means that such explicit solutions must exist).

EDIT: I found an article giving the explicit solution for $\Phi_7$ in radicals, but didn't explain how it got the solution, other than by saying that the methodology does not extend to higher primes.  The solution depends on solving four radicals: $x=\sqrt{-3}, y=\sqrt[3]{14x}, z=\sqrt[3]{-7x}, w=\sqrt{(\frac{y+z-1}{3})^2-4}$.  The explicit solution can then be written as $\frac{y+z+3w-1}{6}$.

Comment: I'm possibly missing something, but assuming  you want $\ g\ne1\ $, then just pick a random element $\ r\ $ of $\ G\ $ and compute $\ g=r^\frac{q-1}{p}\ $.  If $\ g=1\ $, then simply repeat until you get a $\ g\ne1\ $.  You will then have $\ g^p=r^{q-1}=1\ $.  If $\ a\ $ is a primitive element of $\ G\ $, then since each $\ r=a^t\ $ where $\ t\pmod p\ $ is a random element of $\ \{0,1,\dots,p-1\}\ $, and $\ a^\frac{t(q-1)}{p}=1\ $ only if $\ t\equiv0\pmod p\ $ , the probability that $\ g=1\ $ is only $ \frac{1}{p}\ $.  You'd be unlucky to need more than a single trial to get your $\ g\ $.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera: I adjusted my question to specify that I want $g\neq 1$.  It looks like I had missed an obvious solution to my question.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera: I ran your suggestion through a Python script.  It works, and as you said, the probability if a randomly selected $r$ failing is $\frac{1}{r}$.  However, because we can avoid trying $r=\pm1$, this actually translates to a slightly better chance of success of $\frac{\frac{q-1}{r}-2}{q-1}$

Comment: @lonzaleggiera's suggestion is a standard way. It may be a bit unsatisfactory the first time you see it due to the random element, but it works. I'm fairly sure the procedure has been discussed earlier on the site, but I don't have the time to look for a duplicate now.